# Why does scala return an out of range value in this modulo operation?

Tags: scala, math, random

This is a piece of code to generate random Long values within a given range, simplified for clarity:

```
def getLong(min: Long, max: Long): Long = {
  if(min > max) {
    throw new IncorrectBoundsException
  }
  val rangeSize = (max - min + 1L)
  val randValue = math.abs(Random.nextLong())
  val result = (randValue % (rangeSize)) + min
  result
}
```

I know the results of this aren't uniform and this wouldn't work correctly for some values of `min` and `max`, but that's beside the point.

In the tests it turned out, that the following assertion isn't always true:

```
getLong(-1L, 1L) >= -1L
```

More specifically the returned value is `-3`. How is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, `math.abs(x: Long): Long` isn't guaranteed to always return non-negative values! There is no `Long` value that could represent `math.abs(Long.MinValue)`, so instead of throwing an exception, `math.abs` returns `Long.MinValue`:

```
scala> Long.MinValue
res27: Long = -9223372036854775808

scala> math.abs(Long.MinValue)
res28: Long = -9223372036854775808

scala> math.abs(Long.MinValue) % 3
res29: Long = -2

scala> math.abs(Long.MinValue) % 3 + (-1)
res30: Long = -3
```

Which is, in my opinion, a very good example of why one should be using [ScalaCheck](http://www.scalacheck.org/) to test at least parts of their codebase.

Comment: In fact the same happens in many (any?) languages with machine types, not only Scala. E.g. even in Haskell: `abs (minBound :: Int) == minBound` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Since this is the only value for which `abs` is negative, the OP was very, very lucky in detecting the issue during testing.

Comment: Not necessarily lucky. When you get the input random value as the additional input to the function instead of obtaining it in its body and use ScalaCheck for testing, the testing framework pays special attention to extreme values and 0, 1 and -1 and runs into the issue. So taking the functional approach helped my luck a lot ;)

Comment: I see. I thought testing was done more naively, by running `getLong` as it is. Adding the random source as an extra input surely helped here :)